# Django data's not save in db using form

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

views.py

```
def add_phone(request):
    phoneForm = PhoneForm()
    if request.method=='POST':
        phoneForm = PhoneForm(request.POST)
        if phoneForm.is_valid():
            phone=phoneForm.save(commit==False)
            phone.user=request.user()
            phone.save()
        return redirect('/member/contact-list/')

    return render_to_response('incident/add_phone.html',
                  {
                   'about_menu': True,
                   'PhoneForm' :phoneForm
                   },
                 context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

template.py

```
 <form action="/member/add-phone/" method="POST"> {% csrf_token %}
            <table width="100%"  cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="phone">
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2"><h1 align="left">Call - default telephone numbers</h1></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">Set the phone numbers that people should use if they <br />
                        need back-up in dealing with an incident.
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Person or area</td>
                    <td>Phone number</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>{{PhoneForm.number1}}</td>
                    <td>{{PhoneForm.number1}}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>{{PhoneForm.name2}}</td>
                    <td>{{PhoneForm.number2}}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>{{PhoneForm.name3}}</td>
                    <td>{{PhoneForm.number3}}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Emergency</td><td>Phone number</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>{{PhoneForm.emergency}}</td>
                    <td>{{PhoneForm.emergency_number}}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr><td colspan="2" align="right"> <p style=margin-top:2cm;>{% include "buttons/save.html" %}</p></td></tr>
            </table></form>
```

forms.py

```
class PhoneForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Phone_info
```

models.py

```
class Phone_info(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True)
    name1 = models.CharField('Name', max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    number1 = models.CharField('Number',max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    name2 =  models.CharField('Name', max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    number2 = models.CharField('Number', max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    name3 = models.CharField('Name', max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    number3 = models.CharField('Number',max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    emergency = models.CharField('Emergency', max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    emergency_number = models.CharField('Emergency Number',max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
```

I am using models form,while clicking save button page gets navigate but what ever datas i am entering not saving in database.

Thanks

Comment: `commit==False` ? This should be `commit=False`.

Comment: You have a doubled equal sign in `phone=phoneForm.save(commit==False)`. The correct way is with just one: `phone=phoneForm.save(commit=False)`. I'm not saying that's the root of the problem but is it just a typo or you have it like that in your code?

Comment: ya i corrected now,but the problem is still their

Comment: Can you post model's and form's definitions?

Comment: Also, your `return redirect('/member/contact-list/')` is unindented from the `if`. That means the view will always redirect when it is a `post` no matter if the form is valid or not. Check that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have this line when you assign the phone's user:

```
phone.user=request.user()
```

but it should be without the parenthesis because `request.user is not callable`. Correct it like this:

```
phone.user=request.user
```

and give it a try. Your code seems well.

Also, form is probably not validating because you have to add `blank=True` to the user's field declaration in the models just like this:

```
user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True)
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Did it,still the issue is their

Comment: The weird part is that after all those little errors your code didn't throw exceptions. Are you sure your form is passing the `is_valid` proof? It doesn't seem likely

Comment: It is not throwing any exception,fail silently so next what should i check.

Comment: In your model I see a lot of Fields that have the same name `Number`, `Name`, etc. That might affect the form, can you modify that and give them unique names just to be sure?

Comment: Make it scream, include `raise Exception('argh')` inside the if to see if it is entering the `if`. If not, that is the reason why is not saving the phone, a validation issue.

Comment: .is_valid is not working,form validation is not happening,how to solve this

Comment: I think I got it. In `models`, in the user field, declare it like this: `user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True)` The form is not validating because it requires the user.

Comment: How to pass the user through form.

Comment: Well, in your template, if you include {{PhoneForm.user}} that should give you a  `select` field with the users of the db for the user to select but if you want to assign the form just to the user in the session I think you do it the best way.

Answer (score 0):

> while clicking save button page gets navigate but what ever datas i am
>   entering not saving in database.

This is because you don't have an else condition to match your `phoneForm.is_valid()` and since your redirect is part of the outer `if`, the page always redirects even if the form doesn't validate.

Try this version:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def add_phone(request):
    """ Responds to /member/contact-list/ and
        adds a phone to the database """

    phoneForm = PhoneForm()

    if request.method=='POST':
        phoneForm = PhoneForm(request.POST)
        if phoneForm.is_valid():
            phone=phoneForm.save(commit=False)
            phone.user=request.user
            phone.save()
            return redirect('/member/contact-list/')
        else:
            # Form didn't validate
            return render(request,
                          'incident/add_phone.html',
                          {'PhoneForm': phoneForm,
                           'about_menu': True})

    return render(request,
                  'incident/add_phone.html',
                  {'about_menu': True, 'PhoneForm': phoneForm})
```

In your template, make sure you are displaying any errors from the form. See [this section](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#customizing-the-form-template) of the manual on how to customize the error output in your templates.

Comment: Nitpick, you have incorrect `commit==False` from original post.

Comment: I checked with above code,still it is giving me the same issue